# yii pagination for 1 page

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I am currently trying to change the pagination of this page (http://industrialtimesinc.com/index.php/issues) from 10 to 12 or 15 times on each page. 
I have tried to change the pageSize to 12 and it doesn't seem to work.  I would like to change only this page's pagination and not all of the pagination over the whole yii platform.  Any information would help.  Thank you.

```
/**
 * 
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issues',array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'order'=>'date DESC',
            )));
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            $dataProvider->pagination = array('pageSize'=>15),
        ));
}
```

The view:

```
<h1>Publications</h1>
<?php
if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
$this->menu=array(
array('label'=>'Create Issues', 'url'=>array('create')),
array('label'=>'Manage Issues', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);} else{?>
<div class="right_side" style="position: absolute; margin-left: 720px; width: 200px;;"><!--right Col-->
    <div class="right_ads">
        <?php
        echo $this->renderPartial('/site/container/right_ads', array('type' => 'normal','amount' => 4));
        echo $this->renderPartial('/site/container/right_ads', array('type' => 'auction','amount' => 3));
        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

Comment: Pagination is more of a `CGridView` thing but you have pasted some code used for a `CDetailView`? Are you sure we are looking at the correct piece of code?

Comment: I believe you are correct.  I think I was looking at the wrong code.  I should have been looking at the index.php of the view.  I have just updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I needed to edit to controler that renders the view but not set the pagination = false.  What I needed to do is set the pageSize to 12 or 15.  here is the code.

```
/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Issues',array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'order'=>'date DESC',
            )));
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            $dataProvider->pagination = array('pageSize'=>15),
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is to paginate the data more then after that the data is retrieved from the DB.

So you can use this approach: http://yiibook.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/yii-pagination-using-cdbcriteria.html to filter the data from the DB.

Comment: this isn't exactly what I am trying to do.  I just need to change the page size.

Comment: I see, glad that you've found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In the controller that feeds data into this view, try setting `$dataProvider->pagination = false` before rendering the page.

Comment: I am not trying to get rid of the pagination at all.